Accessing RDS instance from EC2 instance in a different VPC [2024]
I have an RDS instance & an EC2 instance in 2 different VPCs. I want to access data in the RDS instance from my EC2 instance. I'm getting timeout errors when I try to connect to the database in the RDS instance.
Here's what I've done:

VPC Peering between the 2 VPCs. DNS resolution is active for receiving and requesting VPCs.

The route tables of both VPCs have been editted such that the destination = <other VPC's IPv4 CIDR range> & target = Peering Connection

The Network ACLs are not an issue.

Updated the security group of the RDS instance to allow inbound traffic from private IPv4 of the EC2 instance.

Tried setting the RDS instance to 'Publically Accessible' & 'Not Publically Accessible' but still gives the same error.

The VPC, which has the RDS, has public and private subnets. I've only updated the route table of the private subnet. I also tried updating the route table of public subnet, but no good.



did you try re:Post? they would guide you with information that is required and that is irrelevant. For example, in your 1: what has DNS have to do with it? 3: If you say so. 5: irrelevant. Now try to set up an EC2 instance in VPC2. Can you connect from that instance to RDS? Can you connect from VPC1 to this instance in VPC2? There is a lot of troubleshooting that has to be done. Stack Overflow is not the right place for it.

Thanks for the suggestion. I asked it there as well.

When your EC2 client attempts to make a connection, is it using the DNS name of the RDS instance? Did you verify that this resolves to the correct private IP in the other VPC? Did you also run a test with network reachability analyzer from the relevant IPs of the EC2 instance to the RDS database?

To test your scenario, I did the following:

Created a Database VPC with only a private subnet and a CIDR of 10.0.0.0/16:



Created an App VPC with one public subnet and a CIDR of 10.1.0.0/16:



Created a VPC Peering connection between the two VPCs and accepted the request:



Edited the Route Table for the App public subnet to point to the Database VPC:



Edited the Route Table for the Database private subnets (I pointed both to the same Route Table) to point to the App VPC:



Launched an Amazon RDS PostgreSQL database in the private subnet of the Database VPC with Publicly accessible = No and auto-creation of the subnet groups
Launched an Amazon EC2 instance in the public subnet of the App VPC
Edited the Security Group attached to the Database to accept incoming connections from the App VPC CIDR (10.1.0.0/16):



Logged into the EC2 instance via SSH
Installed the PostgreSQL client using:

sudo dnf install postgresql15


Connected to the PostgreSQL database from the EC2 instance:

$ psql --host=database-1.cdigff1pjpzh.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --dbname=postgres --username=postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql (15.7, server 16.3)
WARNING: psql major version 15, server major version 16.
         Some psql features might not work.
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> select 42;
 ?column? 
----------
       42
(1 row)

postgres=>

The connection from the EC2 instance in the App-VPC to the database in Database-VPC was successful!
If it is not working for you, then I suggest you cross-check your configuration with what I did above. For example, confirm that you Accepted the peering connection on the receiving side and double-check the Peering configuration.
Good luck! Let us know what you discover!
